# The design of Clustering using MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I have got a similarity matrix like this: `ItemA`, `ItemB`, `Similarity`.

I wanted it to cluster the dataset using algorithm such as `Kmeans` by using `MapReduce`. But I don't know how many `MapReduce`s I should use and how to design them.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a tutorial and not asking a specific question

Comment: How does your data look like? Do you have a similarity matrix or do you have raw data? What is your goal outcome? What do you want to cluster? You mention K-Means, do you know how many centers you want? If not, do you know if you want a partitioning algorithm before running K-Means? If yes, which one? Did you read about that stuff on the internet? Do you want to use any frameworks that help you? What do you mean by `many MapReduces`?  This question is so unclear, I'm boggled that you can get upvotes for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot use k-means with a similarity matrix**. End of story: k-means needs the similarity to the *means*, not between instances. But there are alternative algorithms. Unfortunately, PAM for example scales so badly, it does not pay off to run it on a cluster either.

Other than that, just *experiment*. Choose as many reduces as you have cores, for example; and choose as many mappers as your cluster can sustain (unless your data is too tiny - there should be *several* MB per mapper to make the startup cost pay off)

But I don't think you are ready for that question yet. First figure out what you want to do, *then* how to set parameters that may or may not arise at all..